# Convert any DateTime value to UTC

Tags: c#, .net

I want to convert any dateTime value to UTC. We have a method that takes a dateTime parameter as an input. We assume that value as EST always. But, then not sure if the kind property will be UTC, EST or unspecified. Also, timeZone can be anything. But, irrespective of its kind and timezone info, we know the value that will be passed to that method is EST and want to convert to UTC. What would be the best way?

```
var estTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var newEstDateTimeValue = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(estTime, estTimeZone);
```

I tried above but it throws argument exception because the kind property is utc and I assume sourceTimeZone does not equal Utc and hence as per MSDN website argument exception is expected. But we would like to convert any dateTime value without looking at kind or sourceTimeZone to UTC. Any recommendations would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why not just write an extension method that does this? The extension method can check to see if the date is already UTC. P.S. `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.TryParse` allow you to specify the `DateTimeKind`

Comment: I would like to just ignore kind property and convert every value to UTC.

Comment: So are you saying you want to convert UTC values to UTC? :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd necessarily call [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322896/timezoneinfo-converttimetoutc-issue) a duplicate, but it's very similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When time zones are important to your .NET application, I always recommend the usage of DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime. In most cases you can swap out your use of DateTime easily with DateTimeOffset and not break your code. DateTimeOffset has a method ToUniversalTime() which will give you UTC.

I would also suggest reading this article to understand the difference between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, TimeSpan, and TimeZoneInfo:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime

Comment: So how would I apply DateTimeOffset in the above condition?

Comment: DateTimeOffset estTime; var utcTime = estTime.ToUniversalTime();

Comment: @Mehdi that isn't a good example. How does `DateTimeOffset estTime` get instantiated?

Comment: @John why not? That's exactly what I'm trying to emphasize that Vicky can continue to use her estTime variable if she changes the type to DateTimeOffset and simply call ToUniversalTime() to get UTC.

Comment: estTime already exists in her code. She just needs to change the type to DateTimeOffset as mentioned above. Please review the snippet of code she has pasted as well.

Comment: I have, and it's not clear if the code OP's executing is on a computer in EST, or if OP is receiving a date from a third party, parsing it, and then using the code in the question to force it to be interpreted as EST for the purposes of converting to UTC. If this is the case, then simply changing it to `DateTimeOffset` alone won't solve the problem.

Comment: The OP's post says "We assume that value as EST always". If the post is incorrect and this assumption is not valid, then you would need to convert to UTC from the client by using a library like momentjs. You should still use DateTimeOffset on the backend though.

Comment: I'm not saying the post is incorrect, I'm saying that if it were _local_ time, why isn't OP simply doing `estTime.ToUniversalTime();`? Why the complicated timezone conversion? Reason: The code probably isn't running on a machine whose timezone is EST.

Comment: Only Vicky can answer, but i suspect OP googled "converting between time zones" and chose the guidance on the first search result :) 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones . Vicky, is this a desktop application or a web app with the timezone conversion happening on your backend services?

Comment: This is a webapp. Basically, the dateTime parameters are input parameters for an API endpoint and we have informed all the teams/clients who are going to consume it about our assumption that whatever dateTime they would pass, we would assume it as EST format. So, even if they send us the dateTime Value in UTC, we will convert it in to UTC by adding 4 hours to it in case of daylight saving.

Comment: Great, that was my assumption too. So it doesn't matter if the backend is running in EST or any other timezone. The time will be coming as input from the client and all Vicky is doing is converting it to UTC.

Comment: the concern I have is the date that is passed in the parameter is not a value with DateTimeOffset. How to convert that value to DateTimeOffset?

Comment: @Vicky Change it on your API method. .NET should still deserialize it successfully.

Comment: Just change the type of the parameter to DateTimeOffset and it should continue to work.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot guys

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer if it addresses your needs.